# Delete rows where data has less sum

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
 data_id    sum_value
    xxx        30
    xxx        40
    ccc        50
    aaa        60
    ccc        70
    aaa        80
    ddd        100
    eee        200
```

How would I delete the row where   **`data_id = data_id`**  and **`sum < sum`** ?  Delete rows if data_id = data_id  and sum_value is less and if data_id != data_id then show actual values

***Expected Output***

```
data_id   sum_value
xxx      40
ccc      70
aaa      80
ddd      100
eee      200
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from foo 
using(select min(sum_value) sum
            ,data_id 
     from foo 
     group by data_id  
     having count(data_id)>1
     )t
where foo.sum_value=t.sum 
      and foo.data_id=t.data_id
```

[**SqlFiddle - Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef6db/2)

Comment: deleted all rows from the table

Comment: what is ctid?..is it contid column name

Comment: it works ..but i had made few changes in question can You pls help me  out that..  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 delete from table where data_id=data_id and (SELECT min(the_field) FROM the_table)

 select * from table
```

Comment: delete from table where data_id=data_id and sum 
     = MIN(sum)

Comment: I have tried this also but its showing error like  aggregates not allowed in where clause

Comment: delete from table where data_id=data_id and sum = (SELECT min(sum) FROM table)

Comment: not working ..it has delete all values  which is having minimum sum

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to keep the records with the largest sum (for every id), and delete the rest:

```
-- the data
CREATE TABLE ztable
        ( data_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL
        , sum_value INTEGER NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO ztable(data_id, sum_value) VALUES
 ('xxx',30)
,('xxx',40)
,('ccc',50)
,('aaa',60)
,('ccc',70)
,('aaa',80)
        ;

-- Delete the non-largest per id:
DELETE FROM ztable del            -- del cannot be the record with the largest sum
WHERE EXISTS (                    -- if a record exists
  SELECT * FROM ztable x
  WHERE x.data_id = del.data_id   -- with the same ID
  AND x.sum_value > del.sum_value -- ... but a larger sum
  );
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
DELETE 3
 data_id | sum_value 
---------+-----------
 xxx     |        40
 ccc     |        70
 aaa     |        80
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Maybe your table has a diffent name (you did not specify it, so I had to invent one)

Comment: i have given my table name only dont know y its showing error t "del"

Comment: It works here. (maybe you aren't using postgres, but another DBMS?)

Comment: sql warkbenck/J ,postgressql

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table
USING table, table as vtable
WHERE (NOT table.ID=vtable.ID)
OR sum=(SELECT min(sum) FROM table)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
with src as (
    SELECT DISTINCT on (data_id)
       data_id as di, sum_value as sv
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY data_id, sum_value DESC
 )
 DELETE FROM table1 
 WHERE ( data_id, sum_value) NOT IN (SELECT di, sv FROM src);
```

to only **leave the row with the highest `sum_value`** , or this:

```
with src as (
    SELECT DISTINCT on (data_id)
       data_id as di, sum_value as sv
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY data_id, sum_value ASC
 )
 DELETE FROM table1 
 WHERE ( data_id, sum_value) IN (SELECT di, sv FROM src);
```

to only **remove row with the smallest `sum_value`**.

For supplied data both will do the same. You didn't mention what do you expect where more than two rows exist with the same `data_id`.

see the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92a04/1

Hmm sqlFiddle behaves strange when you modify data in the right pane. When running them both it shows that 0 rows were affected by first one, but then the second on shows only 3 rows left . However, if you run them separately - it shows that no rows were deleted, and all rows still exist. I guess it returns the table for the state defined in the left pane after each run... It has to run it in a transaction. When I added `COMMIT;` statement it threw an error:

> Explicit commits are not allowed within the query panel.

Try theese queries on your local DB - this is how it looks on my local postgres 9.4:

```
testdb=# select * from Table1;
 data_id | sum_value
---------+-----------
 xxx     |        30
 xxx     |        40
 ccc     |        50
 aaa     |        60
 ccc     |        70
 aaa     |        80
(6 wierszy)


testdb=# with src as (
testdb(#     SELECT DISTINCT on (data_id)
testdb(#        data_id as di, sum_value as sv
testdb(#     FROM Table1
testdb(#     ORDER BY data_id, sum_value ASC
testdb(#  )
testdb-#  DELETE FROM table1
testdb-#  WHERE ( data_id, sum_value)  IN (SELECT di, sv FROM src);
DELETE 3
testdb=# select * from Table1;
 data_id | sum_value
---------+-----------
 xxx     |        40
 ccc     |        70
 aaa     |        80
(3 wiersze)
```

re-init table

```
testdb=# select * from Table1;
 data_id | sum_value
---------+-----------
 xxx     |        30
 xxx     |        40
 ccc     |        50
 aaa     |        60
 ccc     |        70
 aaa     |        80
 ddd     |       100
 eee     |       200
(8 wierszy)


testdb=# with src as (
testdb(#     SELECT DISTINCT on (data_id)
testdb(#        data_id as di, sum_value as sv
testdb(#     FROM Table1
testdb(#     ORDER BY data_id, sum_value DESC
testdb(#  )
testdb-#  DELETE FROM table1
testdb-#  WHERE ( data_id, sum_value) NOT IN (SELECT di, sv FROM src);
DELETE 3
testdb=#  SELECT * from table1;
 data_id | sum_value
---------+-----------
 xxx     |        40
 ccc     |        70
 aaa     |        80
 ddd     |       100
 eee     |       200
(5 wierszy)
```

works for me...

Comment: You sure about that? works perfectly on my local DB... I edited the answer and added a printout from my console.

Comment: What dou you mean by "its not working". it gives you an error? doesn't delete row? or what. I dont get it - there is nothing non-standard in that query. What version are you running - maybe you don't have CTE's ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me..your query is fine but i think i have problem with my PostgreSQL version which I'm using

Comment: CTE's where added AFAIR from verxion 9. If you have older - i strongly suggest to update. There are VERY many cool features introduced in newer versions :) check it out here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:What%27s_new_in_this_release